# How to get value by redis-cli keys

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I want get value by redis-cli keys

This is work

```
redis-cli keys number_* | xargs redis-cli del
```

But this is not work

```
redis-cli keys number_* | xargs redis-cli get
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between `DEL` and `GET`, in this context, is that the former is variadic (i.e. accepts one or more arguments) whereas the latter isn't (one and only one key name is expected).

To solve this you can choose one of the following:

1. Use the `-L` switch with xargs, i.e.: `redis-cli keys number_* | xargs -L 1 redis-cli get`
2. Use [`MGET`](https://redis.io/commands/mget), i.e.: `redis-cli keys number_* | xargs redis-cli mget`

#### Important warning: `KEYS` is a dangerous command as it may block the server for a long time - do not use it in production!

Comment: @weiwei you're most welcome, please accept my answer if it had answered your question